# char limit with php file_get_contents() and Google Chart API?

Tags: php, limit, character, google-visualization, file-get-contents

the specific issue I am working on is enabling https with Google charts API, and a possible character limit when using php file_get_contents on a url string. Let me take you through what is going on. I have made good progress using some tutorials on the net, specifically to enable the https. I am using their 'basic method' from this tutorial:

http://webguru.org/2009/11/09/php/how-to-use-google-charts-api-in-your-secure-https-webpage/

I have a chart.php file with this code in it:

```
<?php

$url = urldecode($_GET['api_url']);

$image_contents = file_get_contents($url);
echo $image_contents;
exit;
?>
```

I am calling this file from my main page, passing a 'test' Google chart URL (I have used many different ones) to it, which is 513 chars long:

```
$chartUrl = urlencode('http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxl=0:|Jan|Feb|Mar|Jun|Jul|Aug|1:|100|75|50|25|0&chxt=x,y&chs=300x150&cht=lc&chd=t:60.037,57.869,56.39,51.408,42.773,39.38,38.494,31.165,30.397,26.876,23.841,20.253,16.232,13.417,12.677,15.248,16.244,13.434,10.331,10.58,9.738,10.717,11.282,10.758,10.083,17.299,6.142,19.044,7.331,8.898,14.494,17.054,16.546,13.559,13.892,12.541,16.004,20.026,18.529,20.265,23.13,27.584,28.966,31.691,36.72,40.083,41.538,42.788,42.322,43.593,44.326,46.152,46.312,47.454&chg=25,25&chls=0.75,-1,-1');
```

To display the image in my main page I am using this code:

```
<img src="https://mysite.com/chart.php?api_url=<?php echo $chartUrl; ?>" />
```

The example $chartUrl string should display nothing. It will work fine until the $chartUrl string exceeds 512 characters in length (unencoded). For example if you use this string below (512 chars long):

```
$chartUrl = urlencode('http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxl=0:|Jan|Feb|Mar|Jun|Jul|Aug|1:|100|75|50|25|0&chxt=x,y&chs=300x150&cht=lc&chd=t:60.037,57.869,56.39,51.408,42.773,39.38,38.494,31.165,30.397,26.876,23.841,20.253,16.232,13.417,12.677,15.248,16.244,13.434,10.331,10.58,9.738,10.717,11.282,10.758,10.083,17.299,6.142,19.044,7.331,8.898,14.494,17.054,16.546,13.559,13.892,12.54,16.004,20.026,18.529,20.265,23.13,27.584,28.966,31.691,36.72,40.083,41.538,42.788,42.322,43.593,44.326,46.152,46.312,47.454&chg=25,25&chls=0.75,-1,-1');
```

The chart should show up. The difference between the strings is one character. The 'real' Google chart API string that I will be using in the final version is about 1250 chars long.

So is this a limit on get_file_contents()? I have looked at cURL as an alternative, but its specifics go over my head. Can someone confirm the char limit, and if possible make some suggestions?

Many thanks,
Neil

Answer (score 0):

> **Edit:** Unlike I stated below, this is probably not a server problem: Apache's limit on GET strings is said to be [around 4000 bytes](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html). The workaround I suggest is still valid, though, so I'm leaving this answer in place.

This is an awful lot of data to put in a GET string, and could be a server side limitation (Apache handling the request) as much as a client side one (file_get_contents sending the request).

I would look for an alternative way of doing this, e.g. by storing the long URL in a session variable with a random key:

```
$_SESSION["URL_1923843294284"] = $loooooong_url;
```

and pass that random key in the URL:

```
<img src="https://mysite.com/chart.php?api_url=1923843294284" />
```

Update: There does not seem to be a native length limit to `file_get_contents()` according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549993/maximum-uri-length-for-file-get-contents). This may well be a server issue.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I understand the idea, but I can not get it to work in practice. I am using your code as an example (with urls replaced), I have enabled sessions and have tried online and localhost:

$_SESSION["URL_1923843294284"] = $chartUrl;

<img src="https://mysite.com/chart.php?api_url=URL_1923843294284" />

I have average PHP knowledge, so I accept that I may be doing something wrong, and I guess it is to do with the parsing of the api_url key. I have echoed the session variable, which will work, but again the char limit issue raises its ugly head!

Comment: @Neil you need to initialize a session using `session_start()` in both scripts. Other than that, it should work.

Comment: Awww @Neil I realize only now that maybe, your final URL that gets passed to Google is already > 512 bytes long! In that case, my idea won't do you any good. I apologize. In that case, you may really have to resort to CURL and test whether it is more lenient.